# How can I make the space between links non selectable in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navbar and between my links I have a selectable space. How can I make it non selectable?

This is the code:

```css
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navhome {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.664);
}

.navlinks {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navlinks a {
  font-weight: 570;
  margin-top: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.863);
  margin-left: -4px
}

.navlinks>.navlinks a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="navhome" id="noselect">home</a>
  <div class="navlinks">
    <li><a href="#m">testlink</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="navlinks">
    <li><a href="#">testlink1</a></li>
  </div>

</nav>
```

How can I make the space between links non selectable in html?

Comment: Please create a snippet with the library your are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do this could be as follows.

Put all the links that you have in a `div` or `header` tag and make the display of the element `flex` so that everything inside the `div` or `header` tag get positioned in a line. I've used `align-items` CSS property to centre the links vertically as well. Then for each link declare a left margin or a right margin so that they don't stick to each other.

Note that I have initially set the default margin and padding of all the elements to `0px`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Header-Link {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <header>
    <a class="Header-Link" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Home</a>
    <a class="Header-Link" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Test Link 1</a>
    <a class="Header-Link" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Test Link 2</a>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I made few changes in CSS classes and the format of code and syntax and exclude unnecessary CSS and make it the right way and the spaces between the links are non selectable by simply giving .nav-item a margin-right: 10px;

```css
.navbar{
        background-color: #303030;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    .nav-item{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .nav-item a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
        color: #ffffffdc;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .nav-item a.active{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #daa520;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#" active>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">testlink</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">testlink1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```